# Capturing different values in substring when digits are random - Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, substring

I am working on automation using selenium with Java.
I am using substring in one of my test script where I need to capture the email inbox value. Now this value can be 1 digit, 2 digit or 3 digit. 
The text on browser looks like this - 27 Inbox

So to capture only the numbers I use substring(0,2), which correctly captures the value 27. Problem is when the value becomes 3 digit, example - 110 Inbox. It will only capture 11 and not the 0. If the value is - 5 Inbox then it gives error.
 So how to make the substring work with all there digits

example:
5 Inbox
45 Inbox
126 Inbox

It should capture numbers irrespective of the no of digits.

Comment: Use a regular expression to find `\d+`, or just chop " Inbox" off the end of the string with `s.substring(0, s.length() - " Inbox".length())`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. If you can get the "Inbox" element fine, but are having problems getting the number of emails from text, then it is a normal java substring question and has nothing to do with selenium or automation. Just do what Andy is saying in his answer.
On the other hand if you want to access the element which has "### Inbox" in it by text, you can use xpath like: `WebElement inboxElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[contains(text(),'Inbox')]"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear about the input.

The easiest way to get the leading digits from a string which is formatted as `<digits> Inbox` is just to drop 6 characters off the end of it:

```
String digits = s.substring(0, s.length() - 6);
```

or, if you'd rather be less mysterious about the significance of 6:

```
String digits = s.substring(0, s.length() - " Inbox".length())
```

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression to get a matching group:

```
String digits = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)").find(s).group();
```

Alternatively, you can look through the string for contiguous runs of digits:

```
int start = 0;
while (start < s.length() && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(start))) {
  ++start;
}
int end = start;
while (end < s.length() && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(end))) {
  ++end;
}
String digits = s.substring(start, end);
```

Comment: your solution helps. I tried the 1st option and it works.